# Sorting works, but the data in the table is not sorted - Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

For some reason, the sorting of the mat on the surface has arrows moving, so sorting should work, but it doesn't sort out ...

Here is the HTML :

```html
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
      <!-- name -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{ model.fields.name.label }}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.name }} </td>
      </ng-container>

   <!-- ... -->
  </table>
</div>
```

In my component.ts:

```js
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

export class DevizaListComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<DevizaInterface>(devizas);
  devizas: DevizaInterface[] = [
    {
      name: 'dollar',
      code: 'USD' ,
    },
    //...
    //...
  ];
  //...

  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;


  //...

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
}
```

I imported in my app.module.ts this:

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
  ],
})
```

The console does not display an error message. What is the reason for the problem that arrows appear on the interface for sorting, but the table is not sorted as it should?

Comment: Could you share a jfiddle example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, `this.sort` is not defined yet when you assign it to `this.dataSource.sort` inside `ngOnInit`. Therefore, the `dataSource` does not receive sort events. This may be due to a a structural directive (i.e. `*ngIf`) that only conditionally includes the table in the template.

The problem can be solved by changing the `static` value on the `@ViewChild` and assigning the `sort` inside [`ngAfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) livecycle hook instead. Please consult the Angular documentation about the [component's livecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence).

```
export class DevizaListComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ...

  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false}) sort: MatSort;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

> *You should also change the order of your class members and create `dataSource` after `devizas` has been initialized.*